# R command to change function of x after a point?

Tags: r, function

I'm simulating some data in R, plotting x against Y (a rate) and I want x to be increasing linearly up to a point and then level off. That is, Y is a function of x between say, 0.1 and 5, but constant from 5.01 to 10. Is there a simple command which allows for varying x's? I'm sure my lecturer told me about one but I can't remember it...
Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ifelse`:

```
> f <- function(x) ifelse(x < 5, x**2, 25)
> x <- seq(1, 10, .1)
> plot(x, f(x), type='l')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the example! Managed to get it working using this command.

Comment: If you want to get really fancy, you can extend this to multiple functions over different subdomains of `x` by using the `switch` function.